# Xamarin Touch Tracking (for drawing with SkiaSharp)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, touch, drawing

Today, I have another question about Xamarin. In the Xamarin documentation there is something about `Touch Tracking`, what I want is using the `SkiaSharp` Namespace to do some drawing as user input. So, the user uses his fingers to draw something on a `BoxView` or something like that.

Problem: it's hard to find the namespaces, no trace in the xamarin documentation. Just that the name is "TouchTracking" and I need "TouchEffects" too.

I googled a little and all i got is some 0.1.0 beta stuff where the TouchEffects are not even in the same namespace, but they are in the provided code example, which wouldn't really matter, but the one I found is not for cross-platform and this really bothers me because I have the ambition to do everything via crossplatform if possible.

So are there cross-platform solutions for touch drawing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really hate to answer my own questions but by accident i found out, that SkiaSharp actually supports everything we need. Which is pretty amazing, since after my google research i found out EVERYBODY is looking for it and it seemed only MR Gestures does support what i was looking for.
To the point:
SKCanvasView has a Touch event with arguments (object, SKTouchEventArgs). those event args provide everything you need to draw on the surface, position, type of action (pressed, released, exited, entered, cancelled, ...) 
**but** please notice: you need to enable the handling with setting 'Handled' true, if not the event args will return just Pressed. 
Also you have to enable the Touch Input when creating the SKCanvasView.

Someone should add this to the page provided in the previous answer.

Comment: Do you have any examples? I have drawn a rather complex diagram, that I now need to move and scale, and I am having real trouble working out the syntax for the android xml to attach the event.

Comment: [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55228153/199364).

Answer (score 1):

> So are there cross-platform solutions for touch drawing?

You could refer to this artical : [Invoking Events from Effects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking/).

- Implement low-level multi-touch finger tracking in Xamarin.Forms controls.

Related sample : [Touch-Tracking Effect Demos](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Effects/TouchTrackingEffectDemos)

- This sample demonstrates an effect that implements multi-touch finger tracking, and shows how to trigger events from an effect.

Comment: okay then let's repeat the question:
where do i find that "TouchTracking" namespace and the "TouchEffect" class? it's not integrated in Xamarin i don't know which namespace to use and importing some 0.1.0 beta wasn't working the way it should because it needs Xamarin Forms 2.5+ and my app totally collapses when i try to upgrade to that level

Comment: @KyoshiroKokujouObscuritas - The answer's linked article, in [section: The Touch-Tracking Effect API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking#the-touch-tracking-effect-api) says "The **Touch Tracking Effect Demos** sample **contains** the classes (and an enumeration) that implement the low-level touch-tracking. These types belong to the namespace TouchTracking and begin with the word Touch."