# Why does SkiaSharp Touch SKTouchAction.Moved event not work?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, touch, skiasharp

### Summary

The Touch event is never raised with the ActionType of `SKTouchAction.Moved`, but `SKTouchAction.Pressed` is raised. Why does the `.Moved` event never get raised?

### Detail

I am attempting to create a slider in SkiaSharp. This control will need to update the *thumb* (the little movable circle) when the user either touches on the slider or drags. This is hosted in a Xamarin Forms app, and I have created a `SKCanvasView` to draw the slider and to respond to touch events.

I have successfully responded to touch events, so I know the `SKCanvasView` is receiving some UI events, but the `SKTouchAction.Moved` is never raised.

### Example Code

```
private SKCanvasView CreateSliderControl()
{
    var control = new SKCanvasView();
    control.PaintSurface += HandlePaintHeightControl;
    control.EnableTouchEvents = true;
    control.Touch += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var pt = args.Location;

        switch (args.ActionType)
        {
            case SKTouchAction.Pressed:
                // 1. This code gets hit whenever I touch the canvas
                control.InvalidateSurface();
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Moved:
                // 2. This code never gets hit, even if I push, touch, slide, etc
                control.InvalidateSurface();
                break;
        }
    };
    control.InputTransparent = false;

    return control;
}
```

As shown above `#1` gets hit (I can put a breakpoint there, and my control surface is invalidated). `#2` never gets hit ever, but I expect it to get hit when I slide my finger over the control.

### What I've Tried

- Clean/rebuild to make sure my code actually was being deployed
- Upgrade from SkiaSharp 1.60.3 to 1.68.0
- All the crazy finger movements I could come up with
- Read through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch , but that uses XAML to assign an Effect (which I'm not familiar with) and I don't see a TouchEffect class available anywhere in my code to add it to the parent Grid that contains my `SkiaCanvasView`.

Comment: maybe related?  https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/334

Comment: FWIW the TouchEffect is in a different sample, linked on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found a [similar issue](http://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/334) on SkiaSharp's Github.

Try telling the OS that you want to "continue receiving touch events" by setting the Handled property in the event's args to true.

```
private SKCanvasView CreateSliderControl()
{
    var control = new SKCanvasView();
    control.PaintSurface += HandlePaintHeightControl;
    control.EnableTouchEvents = true;
    control.Touch += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var pt = args.Location;

        switch (args.ActionType)
        {
            case SKTouchAction.Pressed:
                control.InvalidateSurface();
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Moved:
                control.InvalidateSurface();
                break;
        }
        // Let the OS know that we want to receive more touch events
        args.Handled = true;
    };
    control.InputTransparent = false;

    return control;
}
```