# How to draw on a Skiasharp canvas with a tap using SKTouchEventArgs

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Skiasharp canvas that I want to draw markers on when I tap the image. I have this code:

```
        <skia:SKCanvasView Grid.Row="0" 
                           Grid.Column="0" 
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                           EnableTouchEvents="True"
                           Touch="MarkDamage">
            <!-- The Behaviours element binds the canvas to a command responsible for drawing in it. -->
            <skia:SKCanvasView.Behaviors>
                <behaviour:PaintSurfaceCommandBehavior Command="{Binding ShowDamageScreenCommand}" />
            </skia:SKCanvasView.Behaviors>
        </skia:SKCanvasView>
```

Note the `Touch=MarkDamage` attribute. That successfully binds to this method:

```
public void MarkDamage(object sender, SKTouchEventArgs e)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48119146/2119562) answer, all the things I need to draw on my canvas are inside the parameters I'm passed. But I'm struggling to see how. All I want to do is draw a really simple circle on my canvas when I tap it.

Comment: The `PaintSurface` event handler has all the parameters you need to draw. On the `Tapped` event you have to call the `InvalidateSurface` method of `CanvasView`. Could you please check if it helps

Comment: Thanks @Nikhileshwar , it took some work but I managed to implement it.